# wordpress theme's css customization

Tags: css, wordpress

We use modernize theme for our website.

I want to increase the size of main content area. I just want the background image (gray lines) to take mush less space.

I have tried changing theme's own css file & custom css file both. But it's not working.

pls see the website : [www.gtctrust.com](http://www.gtctrust.com)
or the picture below:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9znG8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `!important` as someone just suggested. Just strenghten your selector here from:

```
body .container-wrapper, body .all-container-wrapper.boxed-layout{
     width: 1060px;
}
```

to

```
 body .container-wrapper, body .body-wrapper .all-container-wrapper.boxed-layout{
     width: 1060px;
}
```

Comment: As I said, it's not recomended to use `!important`, because the only way to overwrite an rule using that is also to use `!important`. Use it only in extreme cases. It may work as a temporary solution, but in long cases it will bring you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for you

```
body .container-wrapper, body .all-container-wrapper.boxed-layout{
  width: 1060px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: well it works for me see img above, try `width: 1060px!important`

Comment: thanks so much :) serves the name right-- important! tag